# NgFor to repeat a div form and assign inputs to NgModel

Tags: angular, forms, ngfor

I am doing a form with angular to save some datasets with two inputs: name and  description.
The user has the possibility to add as many as datasets he wants thanks to a button "Add".

In order to do that, I created a list of datasets initialised with one element (*app.component.ts*). 
And then, with a NgFor it generates the number of datasets according to the number of elements in the datasets list.

```
<div *ngFor="let dataset of datasetList; let index = index">
```

I also have an index variable in order to delete one element of the list.

However, I didn't succeed to save the different datasets. It only saves the last one. 
I know that it comes from **[(ngModel)]** in the html code.

But I don't know how to assign this value to the right element in my list.
I tried

```
 [(ngModel)]="datasetList[index].name"
```

But it does not work. I also tried with

```
[(ngModel)]="dataset.name"
```

But same result.
I think I need to make them unique.

Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjlann?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```ts
 addDataset() {
    this.datasetList.push("");
  }
```

to:

```ts
addDataset() {
    this.datasetList.push({});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer to my question. What cezn explained is right and works. However, after that you need to make the name and the [(ngModel)] unique anyway.
This can be done like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let dataset of datasetList;let index = index;">
  <input name=name{{index}} [(ngModel)]="datasetList[index].name" placeholder="item">
</div
```